# Android audio player activity

Tags: android

I have a music player
app I created, while Im playing music and exit the app by pressing home or back button and then launch the app again, it doesn't return to the current state where I exit the app and also the song index goes back to its default value which is 1 but the music is still playing. and when I play music again, the current song I played is still playing. therefore, there are two songs are playing. How can I save the current state of my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the states in onPause() and can retrieve them back in onresume()

Or you can use onwindowFocusChanged() :

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus) 
        //retrive state
    else
        //save state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You really oughta need to read this [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) page which tells you about the life cycle of an activity..

Long answer : what's going on is all your variables are reloading (probaly through onResume or onStart) so you lose state. You can easily save the state of some variable using onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Then reload your variables using onLoadInstanceState.. Easy as that..

More details can be found in this answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/137404

Answer (score 0):

es you can save your current state . just add the following code in your  menifest file .

```
        <activity android:name=".Song_list"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      //the line below will solve your problem just put it in every activity that you created
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>
```